# Is there any other way to develop Android apps in Windows?

Tags: android, eclipse, python-3.x

What do I need to develop android apps in python with eclipse?

I've heard that android apps can be done on eclipse. I've tried [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Tech_Wizard/entry/january_3_2012_11_24_pm19?lang=en) web site, but it doesn't work. What do I do now? Is there any other way to develop Android apps in Windows using Python?

Comment: _"I've tried this web site, but it doesn't work."_ What do you mean? The page doesn't load? Give more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with eclipse but I think you can with visual studios.

Comment: Can you please give me more information on developing android applications using python in vs

Comment: This looks like the best way to use python for android apps. http://kivy.org/#home

Comment: but I want to develop android apps in windows

Comment: can i convert kivy app into apk

Comment: Of course you can or you wouldn't be able to run it on android.